# Asterisk-java-1.0.0.m3.jar and Asterisk 11 issuue

Tags: asterisk

Right Now I'm using Asterisk 11 on centos 6 operating system and using asterisk-java-1.0.0.m3.jar to establish communication between my java application and Asterisk 11.
I'm able to connect my java program with Asterisk
Issues I'm facing are

1.always at console message coming "Unsupported Version Asterisk Use at your own risk"

2.Unable to set property 'state interface' to 'SIP/0010' on org.asteriskjava.manager.event.QueueMemberStatusEvent:no setter found.Please report at http://jira.reucon.org/browse/AJ

My questions are:
1.Is there is asterisk-java-1.0.0.m3.jar source available  anywhere so that i can edit source code and use it
2.I'm able to establish basic sip call,but getting issue as while making other type of calls which use other entities of same station like 0110 & 0210, which saved in extensions.conf & which work fine in Asterisk1.6 but not in Asterisk11.
As per my observation in Asterisk i added AppKonference module which is 3rd party module. & In java Program i write commands for that to establish channels using those entities.
But for communicate AppKonference in Asterisk API helps when Asterisk1.6 but not in 11.

Please suggest what I need to do is there is other asterisk and asterisk jar compatibility issue,if yes then what i need to do.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, source can be found at

https://github.com/srt/asterisk-java

Also you can change agi compatability in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf